# Вывод данных из БД в ListView через CursorLoader

Tags: java, android, база-данных

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь вывести из базы данных данные в `ListView`(который находится во фрагменте)

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

 DBAdapter myDB = new DBAdapter(getActivity());

    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bndl) {
        return new MyCursorLoader(getActivity(), myDB);
    }

    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

          DBAdapter db;

          public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DBAdapter db) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
          }

          @Override
          public Cursor loadInBackground() {
              Cursor cursor = db.getAllRows();
              return cursor;
          }
}
```

Ругается на `getActivity().` Пишет:

```
Required: android.support.v4.content.Loader <android.database.Cursor>
Found: "myPackageNameAndAppName".PageFragment.MyCursorLoader
```

Если `getActivity()` поменять на

```
return new MyCursorLoader(this, myDB)
```

пишет:

```
MyCursorLoader (android.content.Context, DBAdapter) in MyCursorLoader cannot be applied to
    ("myPackageNameAndAppName".PageFragment, DBAdapter)
```

Если написать:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null);
return new MyCursorLoader(view.getContext(), myDB);
```

пишет:

```
Required: android.support.v4.content.Loader <android.database.Cursor>
    Found: "myPackageNameAndAppName".PageFragment.MyCursorLoader
```

Че он ждет? В конструктор MyCursorLoader передаю контекст и базу данных. Че ему не нравится?

Answer (score 2):

У Вас дело совсем не в конструкторе и не в контексте. А в том, что в этом методе

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bndl) {
    return new MyCursorLoader(getActivity(), myDB);
}
```

Обьект `MyCursorLoader` не может быть приведен к типу `Loader<Cursor>`
Пересмотрите импорты, там где-то класс из Support library, а где-то из самой системы, из-за этого и конфликт.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо.
в секции импорта вместо

```
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
```

импортировал:

```
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
```